# How can I change what my Plotly Interactive Graph displays when it hovers over a specific point in the line graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

The title explains it all. Currently it just displays the X and Y values of that specific point but I would like it to display some text that is associated with that point. Is there a way to manually override what is displayed in these interactive plots?

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,7))
plt.plot(X1,Y1, label = 'One')
plt.plot(X2,Y2, label = 'Two')
plt.ylim([-1.0,1.0])
leg = plt.legend(loc='lower right',
       ncol=3,
       fontsize=15,
        fancybox=True)
leg.get_frame().set_facecolor('white')
leg.get_frame().set_edgecolor('grey')
plt.show()

py.iplot_mpl(fig)
```

I'm just converting a simple Matplotlib code to a plotly plot. Any advice will be much appreciated.

-MT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the [`text`](https://plot.ly/python/text-and-annotations/) attribute to your `trace` to control the text which is shown when you hover over the data point.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace0 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3],
    y=[1, 2, 3],
    text=['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
    mode='markers'
)

data = go.Data([trace0])
plot_url = py.plot(data)
```

[image]